# Socket io / node js server - save string to txt file on server

Tags: javascript, sockets, io

I would like my server.js to basically save a string to a .txt file for a history/log on the server.

Since you can not use php or jQuery in server.js, I don't know how to do this, nor has anyone asked the same question.

Do you know how?

Thank you.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the file system library:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Then, you can just output like this:

```
fs.writeFile("log.txt", stringText, function(error) {
    if(error) throw error; // Handle the error just in case
    else console.log("Success!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fs module.

something like that will do the job :

```
let myString = "very very important string";
let fs = require("fs");

// you can use async if you prefer, check the doc
fs.writeFileSync("./myFile.txt", myString);
```